# Global Variables with threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

By threading a process as in this code:

```
import threading
import time

def loop():
    global bbcount
    bbcount = 0
    while True:
        bbcount += 1
        print "This is a Loop"
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threading.Thread(target=loop)
    t.start()
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input("Please enter a value:")
        print "User input: " + user_input
        print "Current count: " + str(bbcount)
    t.join()
```

Do I run the risk of bbcount being corrupted by trying to print a partially updated/incremented memory space while being incremented the loop?

I thought about this after reading:
Since all threads of a process share the same global variables, a problem arises with synchronization of access to global variables. For example, let's assume you have a global variable X and two threads A and B. Let's say threads A and B will merely increment the value of X. When thread A begins execution, it copies the value of X into the registers and increments it. Before it gets a chance to write the value back to memory, this thread is suspended. The next thread starts, reads the same value of X that the first thread read, increments it and writes it back to memory. Then, the first thread finishes execution and writes its value from the register back to memory. After these two threads finish, the value of X is incremented by 1 instead of 2 as you would expect.

from: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of GIL, this program would run expectedly.

More about GIL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock

So the global variables will be thread-safe editing in a short time.